# Get target from JPopupMenu action listener in Java

Tags: java, swing, contextmenu, actionlistener

I'm currently making a TODO GUI app in Java for practice. I want each item added to the list to have an option to be deleted. So I created a context menu (or JPopupMenu in swing). I also added a JMenuItem that will remove the item from the list. But, there is the problem... I added the button an Action Listener and passed an event variable, I firstly though that the event variable is pointing the ListItem but it actually points to the MenuItem.

So, how do I get the target (ListItem) to finnaly remove it from the list?

```
DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
private JList<String> List;

List.setModel(listModel);

JPopupMenu listCtxMenu = new JPopupMenu();

JMenuItem deleteItem = new JMenuItem("Remove Item");
deleteItem.addActionListener(e -> {
    // Access the Target...
});

listCtxMenu.add(deleteItem);

List.setComponentPopupMenu(listCtxMenu);
```

Comment: The answer will depend on a lot of details which you've not provided. Basically, you can attach a mouse listener to each component and when it triggers a popup, you can build the menu dynamically, allowing you to seed the item itself - it's kind of messy. It easier if you're using something like a `JList`

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. I followed MadProgrammer's instructions:

> Basically, you can attach a mouse listener to each component and when
>   it triggers a popup, you can build the menu dynamically, allowing you
>   to seed the item itself.

Thanks.